# Solr-Highlight: unexpected results

Tags: solr, highlighting

I try to use the highlighting function of SOLR 4.4. After some trying it finally works, but not as I expected:

Generell setting: I have a text and a title field. Both are indexed and searched, but the highlighting is only needed in the title field.

- 1st try: title field of a doc was set as `string` => no highlighting-results even though the field was stored
- 2nd try: changed the field to `text_ws` (only `WhiteSpace-Tokenizer`). I was not quite sure whether or not I had to `index` the title field, so I did it. => HL working but only for direct matches (q=Apple didn't HL Apple-Pie in the title - q=Apple-Pie did)
- 3rd try: added `ngram` to the title field. Now the q:apple gives a hit, but highlights the complete Apple-pie, not only the query term.

Now for the question: is that the expected behaviour or is there a way to only highlight the query term

---

**EDIT:** snippets for..

.. solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
        <str name="wt">json</str>
        <str name="indent">true</str>
        <str name="df">text</str>
        <str name="defType">edismax</str>
        <str name="qf">title, text</str>
        <str name="hl">true</str>
        <str name="hl.fl">title</str>
        <str name="hl.simple.pre">&lt;b class="text-success"&gt;</str>
        <str name="hl.simple.post">&lt;/b&gt;</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

.. schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory" />
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" stemEnglishPossessive="0" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" preserveOriginal="1" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German" />
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" preserveOriginal="1" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German" />
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="text_ngrammed" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory" />
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="10" />
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />

        <!--        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/> -->
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>

 <fields>
    <!-- IDs -->
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <!-- Content -->
    <field name="title" type="text_ngrammed" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true" />
    <field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
</fields>
```

Comment: Could you give us your schema.xml, probably relevant requesthandlers from your solrconfig.xml (to check default settings) and a sample request you do? That would help to reproduce things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the tokenizer from `WhiteSpaceTokenizerFactory` to `NGramTokenizerFactory` and removed the `NGramFilterFactory` -> now it's (almost) working as expected